# ValueError: One or more components is not a string or is empty when trying to update a Firestore doc with a dictionary in Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a Google Cloud function with my python script, but I keep getting an error. I am getting an error when trying to update a field in a firestore document with a nested dictionary. Here's my code snippet where it's happening:

```
driverDB = driverDB = db.collection('drivers')
driverList = []
for doc in driverDB.get():
    driverList.append(doc.id)

for driver in range(0,len(driverList)):
    routeDataDict = {
       'route':routeByDriverDict[driver]
    }
   
    driverDB.document(driverList[driver]).update(routeDataDict)
```

The error I get is:

```
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/field_path.py", 
line 272, in __init__ raise ValueError(error) ValueError: One or more components is not a string or is empty.
```

routeDataDict looks like this:

```
{'route': {'stop_1': {'name': 'Christa',
   'address': '742 Evergreen Terrace',
   'phone': 5555555555,
   'email': 'test@test.com',
   'has_reusables': False,
   'notes': None,
   'zone': 1,
   'leg_url': '',
   'seconds_until_arrival': 360.0,
   'completed': False,
   'num_containers_at_this_stop': 0},
  'url': 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/39.74,15.0757',
  'pay': '$49.77',
  'partner': 'burger_hut',
  'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 24, 1, 7, 1, 90282)}}
```

And driverList[driver] correctly prints out the string of the document ID, so the error seems to be in the dictionary.

The full error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", 
line 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", 
line 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", 
line 39, in reraise raise value File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", 
line 1936, in dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) File "/layers/google.python.functions-framework/functions-framework/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 66, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object()) File "/workspace/main.py", 
line 282, in routeCreatorMain driverDB.document('Lu2qHfOqtma48r7L2g4PsEDQizD2').update({'route':routeByDriverDict[driver]}) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py", 
line 284, in update batch, kwargs = self._prep_update(field_updates, option, retry, timeout) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_document.py", 
line 232, in _prep_update batch.update(self, field_updates, option=option) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_batch.py", 
line 126, in update write_pbs = _helpers.pbs_for_update( File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", 
line 847, in pbs_for_update extractor = DocumentExtractorForUpdate(field_updates) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py",
 line 798, in __init__ super(DocumentExtractorForUpdate, self).__init__(document_data) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", 
line 422, in __init__ for field_path, value in iterator: File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", 
line 369, in extract_fields for s_path, s_value in extract_fields(value, field_path): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", 
line 369, in extract_fields for s_path, s_value in extract_fields(value, field_path): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", 
line 364, in extract_fields sub_key = FieldPath(key) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/field_path.py",
 line 272, in __init__ raise ValueError(error) ValueError: One or more components is not a string or is empty.
```

When I run my code in a jupyter notebook, it all works fine. When I run it in cloud functions, I get the above error. When I copy the dictionary insides and hardcode it into the update command on cloud functions, it works. But when I print the dictionary to the cloud functions log, and then copy and paste that into the update function it does NOT work. Something seems to be happening with the cloud function that is messing up the dictionary.

This is the data on firestore (this is an old route currently in there)
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the value of `driverList[driver]` just before the error?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson it is a string that is the name of the document id. It's the UID of a user. I've tested that out by passing a simple dictionary to the update command and the update works and updates the document in firestore. Seems to be an issue with the nested dictionary.

Comment: So, when you log it, what is its exact value?

Comment: When I log the UID it is some character string like "Lu2qHfOqtma48r7L2g4PsEDQizD2" and it's of class str. The dictionary looks like the one posted above. Interestingly, when I copy and paste that dictionary from my jupyter notebook into cloud functions, it works. But when I print the dictionary into my google cloud function logs, and then copy and paste that to hardcode it into the cloud function, it doesn't work. Something is happening in google cloud functions to not be able to process the dictionary correctly. And all of my code worked perfectly fine when running it in a jupyter notebook

Comment: could you share the data structure as is on firestore.  Is `stop1` a map?

Comment: @SoniSol Hi, yes stop1 is a map. But many times I'm updating route when it is just an empty map in firestore. I've uploaded a picture of the data structure

Answer (score 2):

you cannot store keys as integers in firestore. It's like JSON. Try doing `json.loads(json.dumps(your_dict))` this will convert your dict integer keys to string. Now you can write this to firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `doc.id` isn't an integer?
If it an integer then try casting in into a string (`doc.id.toString()`) because firestore accept key as only `string` or `null`

Comment: Yes it includes characters in it. It's firebase auth UID string. I've also tested it by passing a simple test dictionary and it updates properly